# Prove that $(\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z})^\times =\{a \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\, :\, (a,n) = 1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

To me, this question seems to be asking me to prove the definition of congruence class. So, I don't understand.

My textbook gives this nearly exact same notation as the definition for $\mathbb{Z}/ n\mathbb{Z}$ in the first place. But, the title reflects a proposition 4 that I am supposed to prove. [image]

So, to clarify my question...I am supposed to prove proposition 4 (as shown in the image). And, I wrote "conjugacy class" before but as someone below pointed out, I meant to say "congruence class." I edited this update.

Comment: It's hard to answer this without knowing what definition of conjugacy class or of $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ you have. For me a conjugacy class looks like $[a] = \{a + kn : k \in \mathbf{Z}\}$ and $\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z} = \{[a] : a \in \mathbf{Z}\}$ and to me these look completely different than what you have for $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})^\times$.

Comment: You say your book gives "this nearly exact same notation" as the definition. What do you mean by "nearly"? Is there some small difference?

Comment: I updated the original post with the actual question. I should have just used the image in the first place :) so, to me it's all saying the same thing and I'm confused which part I am supposed to prove.

Comment: I suppose you mean `congruence class`, not `conjugacy class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align*}
(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^* &= \{ \bar{a}\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}~|~ \mbox{there exists } \bar{c} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} ~\mbox{with} ~\bar{a}\cdot \bar{c} = 1 \} \\
 &=\{ a \in \mathbb{Z}~|~ \mbox{there exists } c \in \mathbb{Z} ~\mbox{such that} ~a\cdot c \equiv 1\pmod{n} \} \\
&=\{a \in \mathbb{Z}~|~ \mbox{there exists } c \in \mathbb{Z} ~\mbox{such that} ~a\cdot c = 1+n\cdot t,~ \mbox{for some}~t \in  \mathbb{Z} \} \\
&=\{ a \in \mathbb{Z}~|~ \mbox{there exists } c \in \mathbb{Z} ~\mbox{such that} ~a\cdot c +(-n)\cdot t= 1,~ \mbox{for some}~t \in  \mathbb{Z} \} \\
&=\{a \in \mathbb{Z}~|~ \gcd(a,n) =  1 ~\mbox{by Bézout's theorem} \}\\
&=\{\bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}~|~ \gcd(a,n) =  1\}
\end{align*}

Comment: Except that the intermediate sets are all "$\bar{a}\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$" not "$a \in \mathbb{Z}$".

Comment: OH, I see the point now. I was supposed to recognize the difference between an element and a congruence class and fill in the details to get from the definition to Proposition 4. Sometimes just seeing it written out helps immensely. Thank you so much!